# How to make a list view with multiple columns from single lookup column?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

For example: I have 2 lists (company and workers)
I would like to make a worker list view that will display all needed worker data + company.name + company.id

I know lookup field will display one specified column, but how can I bind another one to same lookup?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the new lookup column in your workers list, it would ask you for the list from which you want to lookup (company in our case).

After that you need to specify which column's value you want to use as lookup value (this is the one specified column that you have said in your question).

Underneath that it would show a list of all columns available in the looked up list.

[image]

Select all columns that you want to show from your looked-up (company) list into your (worker) list view.

[image]

*Note*: dont think that now you would be asked for values of all these other selected columns when you are creating a new (worker) item. It would only ask for the primary column value (company title in our example). The other selected columns are only for display purpose and fetch values directly from looked-up list item.

*You can also find my detailed blog post on this matter [here](http://purnil.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/make-a-list-view-with-multiple-columns-from-single-lookup-column/).*

Comment: Unfortunately not all fields from the partent list can be displayed like that. You can't pick any Choice fields, for example.